# Does anyone know why my app won't show on the android market for an Acer Liquid Mini?

Tags: android, google-play

I just put an app on the market and it is showing on all phones I have except for my Acer Liquid Mini. This one:

http://www.gsmarena.com/acer_liquid_mini_e310-3711.php

I have phones with the same res screens, Android 2.2, and close enough to the same hardware specs yet this is the only phone that it doesn't show for. It is running on factory defaults. When I try to install by the browser Google just says that the app isn't compatible and no more information.

I have the minSDK set to 4, maxSDK set to 10, I'm not specifying any screen resolutions in the Manifest (as recommended by the Android Doc post Android 1.6) and install location is set to "auto".

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Google has problems with knowing the hardware constraints on some devices, such as this one, my Desire with the 2.3 upgrade and my Irish Galaxy 10.1" tab. They are working to sort it out

Answer (score 0):

You could try deploying you app on [appslib](http://www.appslib.com/), they got a list of devices supported. You can choose a set of features required by your app and see the devices that will be able to run it.

I can't promise that both Android Market and appslib will give you the same results, i.e. will associate a device to the same requirements but that's a track to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I can see, that website is purely for tablets. My app is for android phones. That website does seem to be very, very useful for tablet development though. Thanks.

Comment: They seem to be aimed at tablets and tablet-type devices (minimum resolution being 800x480). The Acer that I'm talking about is 320x480. I don't think it's ideal adding my app to another market to solve this. But thanks anyway.